# Extract values from [x,y,z] in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to turn a field plate containing [1,2,3,4] into 4 different fields for each value in the string. The string is always 4 values comma separated in bracket e.g. [1,2,3,4]

Comment: What is your Oracle Database version?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '[1,2,3,4]' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) val_1,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) val_2,
  5         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) val_3,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) val_4
  7  from test;

VAL_1 VAL_2 VAL_3 VAL_4
----- ----- ----- -----
1     2     3     4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, you can use dedicated JSON functions. Here is one way:

Table setup

```
create table table_name ( id number, value varchar2(200) );
insert into table_name ( id, value ) values ( 1054, '[1,2,3,4]' );
insert into table_name ( id, value ) values ( 1017, '[0,2,2,7]' ); 
commit;
```

Query and output

```
select id, value1, value2, value3, value4
from   table_name
       cross apply
       json_table( value, '$'
                   columns value1 number path '$[0]',
                           value2 number path '$[1]',
                           value3 number path '$[2]',
                           value4 number path '$[3]'
                 )
;

        ID     VALUE1     VALUE2     VALUE3     VALUE4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1054          1          2          3          4
      1017          0          2          2          7
```

MT0 posted a different JSON-specific solution, using multiple calls to `JSON_VALUE`. In principle, that would require the JSON strings to be parsed four different times; `JSON_TABLE` gets all the values in a single pass.

Happily, Oracle knows about this issue too; the optimizer will re-write MT0's answer to - essentially - the query I show in my answer. This is true in Oracle 12.2 and higher; I am not sure if this optimization was available in 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_VALUE` to extract the numbers:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE( value, '$[0]' ) AS value1,
       JSON_VALUE( value, '$[1]' ) AS value2,
       JSON_VALUE( value, '$[2]' ) AS value3,
       JSON_VALUE( value, '$[3]' ) AS value4
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(200) );
INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '[1,2,3,4]' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 | VALUE4
> :----- | :----- | :----- | :-----
> 1      | 2      | 3      | 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d639f5b956950bdbeb34f1a1a3ccd2bd)*